# Could not find class error in Autolab assignment

Tags: java

I am trying to sort an `ArrayList` in increasing order in reference to a certain variable. This is the problem question.

> q5: Create a public class named `Snow` with private instance variables `vast`, `prior`, `ethnic`, and `remarkable` each of type `int`. You may add any other methods and variables you'd like to this class.
>
> Outside of `Snow` (in the Problem Set class) write a public static method named `sortSnow` that takes an `ArrayList` of Snows as a parameter and returns void. This method will sort the input by the variable `remarkable` in increasing order

This is what I wrote.

```
public class snow implements Comparable<snow> {
    private int vast;
    private int prior;
    private int ethnic;
    private int remarkable;

    public snow( int vast , int prior, int ethnic ,int remarkable) {
        this.vast=vast;
        this.prior = prior;
        this.ethnic = ethnic;
        this.remarkable = remarkable;
    }

    public int getEthnic() {
        return ethnic;
    }

    public void setEthnic(int ethnic) {
        this.ethnic = ethnic;
    }

    public int getPrior() {
        return prior;
    }

    public void setPrior(int prior) {
        this.prior = prior;
    }

    public int getVast() {
        return vast;
    }

    public void setVast(int vast) {
        this.vast = vast;
    }

    public int getRemarkable() {
        return remarkable;
    }

    public void setRemarkable(int remarkable) {
        this.remarkable = remarkable;
    }

    public int compareTo(snow compareSnow) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int compareThese = ((snow) compareSnow).getRemarkable(); 

        //ascending order
        return this.remarkable - compareThese;
    }

    }
    public static void sortSnow(ArrayList<snow>input){
         Collections.sort(input);  
    }
```

I am not understanding what the error means. The autolab is giving me this error:

> Could not find class `submission.ProblemSet$Snow`

Comment: Can you tell us what is the problem ? See how to provide a [mcve] and [edit] your question. And Welcome !

Comment: You are supposed to write a `Snow` class nested inside the `ProblemSet` class. Not a `snow` class.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your question is. Use `List.sort` or `Collections.sort` with an appropriate `Comparator`

Comment: when i submit my problem it says its wrong and Could not find class submission.ProblemSet$Snow. I dont understand where Im wrong. and what does the error mean?

Comment: How, be careful on the formatting next time. I didn't catch most of the description. [Burkhard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50147784/4391450) will help you. But you might need to check the full hierarchy of your class. "_Could not find class submission.ProblemSet$Snow_" means that the `Snow` should be an inner class of `ProblemSet`.

Comment: @AxelH I'm fine to reopen when the question is corrected.

Comment: @AxelH I've corrected the title. But now I can't close it again (as it should be). :)

Comment: Me neither @lexicore ... but at least, justice have been done ;) I know we could have let it closed but an incorrect flag on rookie can be frustrating for them.

Comment: @AxelH I totally agree with you. The corrected question (and answers) are now more useful for future readers. I regret I was mistaken with the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Java is case sensitive i.e. snow is not Snow is not sNoW. Rename your class to Snow and try again. Also, it is ArrayList and not arraylist.

Then to sort a List, you can use `Collections.sort`.

Answer (score 0):

**I think this is you want to achieve**

> Save below code in file called "Snow.java" compile it and try to run it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

//As ".java" file can contain only single public java class
//I made Problem set class non-public so we can use its main method
//to run and see output

class ProblemSet {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Snow one = new Snow(1,1,1,1);
    Snow two = new Snow(1,1,1,2);
    Snow three = new Snow(1,1,1,3);
    Snow four = new Snow(1,1,1,4);
    Snow five = new Snow(1,1,1,5);
    Snow six = new Snow(1,1,1,6);

    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
    arrayList.add(one);
    arrayList.add(three);
    arrayList.add(five);
    arrayList.add(two);
    arrayList.add(six);
    arrayList.add(four);

    System.out.println("Without sort");
    System.out.println(arrayList);

    sortSnow(arrayList);

    System.out.println("With sort");
    System.out.println(arrayList);

}

//this is your static method which takes argument as array list of Snow
//And it applies sorting logic based on compareTo method which you wrote
//in Snow class. As per java best practice Class name should start with 
//Upper case letters and follow camel casing I renamed your class from 
//"snow" to "Snow"
public static void sortSnow(ArrayList<Snow> input){
    Collections.sort(input);
}

}

//This is you public class Snow
//If you want to keep it in separate java file put it

public class Snow implements Comparable<Snow> {
private int vast;
private int prior;
private int ethnic;
private int remarkable;

public Snow(int vast, int prior, int ethnic, int remarkable) {
    this.vast = vast;
    this.prior = prior;
    this.ethnic = ethnic;
    this.remarkable = remarkable;
}

public int getEthnic() {
    return ethnic;
}

public void setEthnic(int ethnic) {
    this.ethnic = ethnic;
}

public int getPrior() {
    return prior;
}

public void setPrior(int prior) {
    this.prior = prior;
}

public int getVast() {
    return vast;
}

public void setVast(int vast) {
    this.vast = vast;
}

public int getRemarkable() {
    return remarkable;
}

public void setRemarkable(int remarkable) {
    this.remarkable = remarkable;
}

public int compareTo(Snow compareSnow) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    int compareThese = ((Snow) compareSnow).getRemarkable();

    //ascending order
    return this.remarkable - compareThese;

}

//This is added because when you use array list to print
//it will print remarkable of particular Snow object
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(remarkable);
}
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you are doing instead of posting a full code on an answer that only required a few updates.